# Ganglia:No nodes were viewed in ganglia web (centOS7)

Tags: monitor, centos7, ganglia, gmetad

I installed ganglia server and client at the same machine. But no nodes can view in the web when it finished. No matter google or baidu,no resolution about this problem appeared.I need help.

So this is my **gmetad.conf**:
[root@tools etc]# egrep -v "^#|^$" gmetad.conf

```
data_source "trainor" localhost 127.0.0.1
setuid_username "apache"
rrd_rootdir "/var/lib/ganglia/rrds"
case_sensitive_hostnames 0
```

here is my gmond.conf:
[root@tools etc]# egrep -v "^#|^$" gmond.conf

```
globals {
    user = apache
}
cluster{
    name = "trainor"
    owner = "apache"
    latlong = "unspecified"
    url = "unspecified"
}
udp_recv_channel {
    port = 8649
}
tcp_accept_channel {
    port = 8649
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `udp_send_channel` set? In my experience (3.1.7), gmond doesn't report a node's own stats over the TCP channel (xml reporting) unless it receives them over UDP (raw stats collection).

You can use "gstat" to connect to gmond to see what it's outputting, or netcat to the TCP port:

```
nc node1.domain.com 8649
```

I found these pages the most useful:

- https://github.com/ganglia/monitor-core/wiki/Ganglia-Quick-Start
- http://timstaley.co.uk/posts/ganglia-setup-explained/